# Reading a CSV with file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am reading a 'kind' of csv file and exploding it and storing it in array.

The file I am reading has this structure

```
Id,Log,Res,File

mydb('Test1','log1','Pass','lo1.txt').
mydb('Test2','log2','Pass','lo2.txt').
mydb('Test3','log3','Pass','lo3.txt').
```

Now what I am trying to do is :
reading the last record in my database, get the Name, lets say in this case 'Test1' and then I am searching through my file and where I can find the position of 'Test1' and get the next lines in the file, extract the ID,s and add it to database.

I am getting the position of desired string in the file, but I am not sure how to get the next lines too.

Here's my code so far.

```
<?php


    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("testing") or die(mysql_error());



$result = mysql_query("select ID from table_1 order by  S_no DESC limit 1") or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
$a = $row['ID'];
echo 'Present Top Row is '.$a.'<br>';

$addresses = explode("\n", file_get_contents('\\\\fil1\\logs\\tes.pl'));

    foreach($addresses as $val)
    {

    $pos = strstr($val, $a);

    if ($pos === false) {

    } else {
        echo "The string <br> '$a' <br>was found in the string <br>'$val' <br>";
        echo " and exists at position <br>$pos<br>";


    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand you correctly. If so you could just set a flag once the item is found and then explode each line then on a ' character. The second value in the resultant array should then contain the id as per your example.

```
$addresses = explode("\n", file_get_contents('\\\\fil1\\logs\\tes.pl'));

$bFound = false;
foreach($addresses as $val)
{

    if (!$bFound) {
      $pos = strstr($val, $a);

      if ($pos === false) {          

      } else {
          echo "The string <br> '$a' <br>was found in the string <br>'$val' <br>";
          echo " and exists at position <br>$pos<br>";
          $bFound = true;
      }
    }
    else {
      $aCols = explode("'", $val);
      $sId = $aCols[1];
      // Now add Id as stored in $sId to DB here
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is supposed to be unique, the traffic between the php process and the MySQL server is not *the* limiting factor and you have to parse each line anyway, you could [create a unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) and let MySQL decide whether it accepts the record or not.

Simple example:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'localonly', 'localonly'); 
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$pdo->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (Id varchar(16),Log varchar(16),Res varchar(16),File varchar(16), unique key(Id))');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO foo (Id,Log,Res,File) VALUES(?,?,?,?)');
$pattern = '/(?<=^mydb\().+(?=\)\.$)/';
$fp = 'dummy';
while ( false!==($row=dummy_fgets($fp)) ) {
  if ( preg_match($pattern, $row, $m) ) {
    $row = str_getcsv($m[0], ',', "'");
    $stmt->execute($row);
    echo $row[0], ' -> ', $stmt->rowCount(), "\n";
  }
}

function dummy_fgets($dummy) {
  static $data = array(
    "mydb('Test1','log1','Pass','lo1.txt').\n",
    "mydb('Test2','log2','Pass','lo2.txt').\n",
    "mydb('Test3','log3','Pass','lo3.txt').\n",
    // start again ...like you process the same file again + 1 new record
    "mydb('Test1','log1','Pass','lo1.txt').\n",
    "mydb('Test2','log2','Pass','lo2.txt').\n",
    "mydb('Test3','log3','Pass','lo3.txt').\n",
    "mydb('Test4','log3','Pass','lo3.txt').\n"
  );
  $rv = current($data);
  next($data);
  return $rv;
}
```

prints

```
Test1 -> 1
Test2 -> 1
Test3 -> 1
Test1 -> 0
Test2 -> 0
Test3 -> 0
Test4 -> 1
```